# service start jenkins- jenkins.service failed because the control process exited with error code

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, installation, devops

I installed jenkins on Aws linux

```
sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo http://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.repo
sudo rpm --import http://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.io.key
yum install jenkins
```

as described on the official documentation

However when I run:

service start jenkins
I get the following error message:

```
Starting jenkins (via systemctl):  Job for jenkins.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status jenkins.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
                                                           [FAILED]
```

Running systemctl status jenkins.service gives me this:

● jenkins.service - LSB: Jenkins Continuous Integration Server
Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/jenkins)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2016-09-21 16:45:28 BST; 3min 59s ago
Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 2818 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/jenkins start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 21 16:45:28 webstack.local.caplib jenkins[2818]: at com.sun.akuma.JavaVMArguments.of(JavaVMArguments...04)
Sep 21 16:45:28 webstack.local.caplib jenkins[2818]: at com.sun.akuma.JavaVMArguments.current(JavaVMArgu...92)
Sep 21 16:45:28 webstack.local.caplib jenkins[2818]: at com.sun.akuma.Daemon.daemonize(Daemon.java:106)
Sep 21 16:45:28 webstack.local.caplib jenkins[2818]: at com.sun.akuma.Daemon.all(Daemon.java:88)
Sep 21 16:45:28 webstack.local.caplib jenkins[2818]: ... 6 more
Sep 21 16:45:28 webstack.local.caplib systemd[1]: jenkins.service: control process exited, code=exited s...s=1
Sep 21 16:45:28 webstack.local.caplib systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
Sep 21 16:45:28 webstack.local.caplib systemd[1]: Unit jenkins.service entered failed state.
Sep 21 16:45:28 webstack.local.caplib systemd[1]: jenkins.service failed.
Sep 21 16:45:28 webstack.local.caplib jenkins[2818]: [FAILED]
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.

After doing all jenkins setup in my AWS machine we got error-----
Starting jenkins (via systemctl):  Job for jenkins.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status jenkins.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[FAILED]

**I have a work around this. please try once and vote here .**

```
1)Uninstall all  java version installed
command- sudo yum remove java*   

2) install java 11 by using below command
 command -sudo amazon-linux-extras install java-openjdk11
```

i'm sure it will resolve your issue .
Note: this issue is because our Jenkins were updated and few things in Java8 was not compatible with latest Jenkins version

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Java 11, not Java 8. I have documents all the commands to do so:

1. `sudo yum install java-11-amazon-corretto-headless`
2. `sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo http://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.repo`
3. `sudo rpm --import http://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.io.key`
4. `sudo yum install jenkins`
5. `sudo systemctl restart jenkins`
6. `sudo systemctl enable jenkins`

#### Configuring Jenkins

Jenkins is now installed and running on your EC2 instance. To configure Jenkins:

1. Connect to `http://<your_server_public_DNS>:8080` from your browser. You will be able to access Jenkins through its management interface.
2. Unlock Jenkins: `sudo cat  /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword`

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same error because I have made some changes in the folder permission,

> chown -R root:root /var/lib/jenkins
>
> chown -R root:root /var/cache/jenkins
>
> chown -R root:root /var/log/jenkins

and changes the JENKINS_USER from "jenkins" to "root"
in the /ect/sysconfig/jenkis.

Changes the permission to jenkins user and it start working.